# Remote connection to oracle database running on a docker container from outside the docker's host machine

Tags: docker, oracle12c, sqlplus

I have been recently trying to set up an Oracle Database Server 12c R2 using its official docker images from [this website](https://hub.docker.com/u/hamednq/content/sub-f12a3e99-85f2-4284-88e2-b561dfd17911), and I've successfully run a container from that image and connected to the database both from the inside of the container and its outside (from the docker host machine). 
The docker host machine is a VPS (ubuntu 16.04), and I have telnet to the IP/PORT of the database from my laptop (centos 7), but I'm not able to connect to the database using sqlplus command. The tnsnames.ora file is something like this:

```
ORCLCDB = (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 217.182.235.26)(PORT = 32756)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = ORCLCDB.localdomain)))
ORCLPDB1 = (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 217.182.230.21)(PORT = 32756)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = ORCLPDB1.localdomain)))
```

and the listener.ora is like this:

```
LISTENER = (DESCRIPTION_LIST = (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 217.182.235.26)(PORT = 32756)) (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))))
DIAG_ADR_ENABLED = off
SSL_VERSION = 1.0
```

and the command that I'm using to connect from my local machine is:

```
sqlplus64 UI_TEST/ut@217.182.235.26:32756/ORCLCDB.localdomain
```

But I get `ORA-12537: TNS:connection closed`

What is the problem?
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

There can be various possible reasons for the error you are observing. Can you check if any of these [solutions](https://www.oradev.com/ORA-12537_TNS_connection_closed.html) lands you to success.

Also worth checking if you can map a host port to dockerised listener port, therein making a tunneling mechanism to get your connections passed in.